# Wrongly migrated from Physics SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

The question [What are the implications of deterministic chaos: useful or detrimental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4112920/418568) has just been migrated from Physics SE.

Since it's mostly about modeling, about the consequences in the physical world of the system being chaotic, it seems to me to be a typical problem in the field of Nonlinear dynamics and chaos (in Physics). On the other hand, the overlap with Applied math is obvious (though isn't it true to almost everything done in Nonlinear dynamics and chaos?), even if most questions under the tag `chaos-theory` here are of a more formal nature. So I'd like to ask:

- Is the question a better fit to Math SE or Physics SE?

I disagree with the migration, but I'm not complaining about it -- I'd just like to know the view of the community. Also, I know it will probably not be migrated back even if it's thought to be a better fit in physics, since the process [is complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106675/369732) and the mods should have better to do.

**Update** [26 April 2021]: The post in question has just closed in Math SE as well - bouncing it back to [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/630421/75633), as quid had explained it would.

Comment: This strikes me a good question for mathematics actually, and it doesn't feel like a physics question.  Chaos theory is an established mathematical field and while the question references biological systems they are the standard exemplars when studying chaos theory mathematically.  I cannot find anything in the question or the (good) answers that would indicate it belongs on Physics.SE

Comment: Re: "I know it will probably not be migrated back even if it's thought to be a better fit in physics, since the process is complicated and the mods should have better to do." That's outdated. It does not even need to involve mods. Get it closed here and it is sent back. Note though that it will be in "closed" state back  where it came from. Thus you'd need to get it reopened there. To be clear that's a general remark I did not look at the particular post at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @quid.

Comment: Maybe the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) could be suitable here? See [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for details on the usage of this tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Done. It'd be great to see a discussion on the boundary between math and physics in Nonlinear Dynamics, but this question is indeed primarily about a specific post.

Comment: I think postmortes's comment addresses your point. For discussions you could also ask on [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=math.stackexchange.com), maybe [Calvin's chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110884/calvins-chat-room).

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. It's an idea, the problem being that those chats are not very lively.

Comment: @postmortes But then which kind of questions in chaos do you feel belong to physics, apart from application to physical systems? To make it clear: I don't think it doesn't belong to mathematics, it does, but it _also_ belongs to physics, so I don't see why it had to be migrated.

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on what questions Physics.SE should or shouldn't answer I'm afraid; I'm not a member there and I don't plan on joining anytime soon.  My comment was only to note that there was nothing especially physics-y about these question so I have no problem with it being on Math.SE

Comment: @postmortes I really meant "physics" and not Physics SE - you said that "[the post] doesn't feel like a physics question", which does sound like you do have an opinion on that.

Comment: I appreciate from your comments above that you'd like to have a discussion about this, but I'm not actually interested in such a discussion.  I do hope you can find people who are though, as it's clear this is important to you

Comment: It's alright, @postmortes, I wanted to understand on what your initial comment was based, but I have no intention of dragging you into a discussion you don't care about. Farewell.

Comment: FWIW if things are going as they should, the question was migrated because the Physics SE community decided it was not on topic there. So the useful thing to ask is not whether the question is a _better fit_ there or here, it's whether the question fits here or not, because the only other alternative (except in very unusual situations) is that it gets closed permanently on both sites, end of story.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for dropping in. I'm asking because in my view this migration was unwarranted, i.e., things actually did not go as they should. As quid explained in a comment, closing it here within 30 days actually bounces the question back to Physics SE -- and exactly that has just happened, so maybe this meta question wasn't so useless if it prompted some vote-to-close. :-) If the community there decides to keep it closed (for its vagueness or any other reason), I can live with it, but migrating to Math was not right and I'm glad it's been corrected.

Comment: If you believe that the migration was unwarranted, you need to communicate with the community that decided upon the migration, not the community which was the target of the migration.  As David Z said, we can only help you determine if the question is on-topic **here**, not if it is on-topic on [physics.se].

Comment: @XanderHenderson I hope to get down to starting a discussion there too, but once the migration had been made, only here in Math could it be undone (as it indeed happened). Besides, that's why I labeled my post here `discussion`, to get your feedback, which I value very much, since the subject is essentially the boundary between math and physics when it comes to Nonlinear dynamics and Chaos, so both the opinions of physicists and mathematicians are relevant.

Comment: As a long-time member of the physics.SE community, I can offer a reasonably educated guess that the reason it was closed there is that it asks about applications to biology rather than physics. Although a lot of professional physicists apply the techniques of physics to other fields, the physics.SE crowd are really quite specific about only allowing questions about physics itself. On the other hand it's clearly on topic here IMHO, and a bit of a shame that it was migrated back.

Comment: @Nathaniel I think your guess is probably right. That's why I think migrating here was mistake and/or driven by prejudice, and I'm glad it was undone. If the question had been asked here and migrated there I'd also consider it wrong, since it's on-topic here (though most other questions here seem more formal than this one to me). But I had to pay a price for that: an upvote for my answer and a good deal of my few points in Math SE are gone. ;-)

Comment: @stafusa I don't think it was incorrect to migrate it. I've never liked the "only questions about physics" policy on physics.SE. It presents a needless gotcha for new users and often results in interesting questions being closed, and I've argued for changing it a few times over the years. But it's a very long-standing policy and that question does violate it, so absent a fairly major change it genuinely is off topic there.

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh, I very much disagree with that the question is off-topic there. If it were most questions on chaos would also be.

Comment: @stafusa if you ask a question on the physics meta I will enthusiastically vote that it should be considered on-topic, and I encourage you to do that if you've got the energy for it. But from past experience I'm not super optimistic that the community there will agree.

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks for the support and, yes, I did consider opening the discussion, but was deterred by lack of time and hope...